# I want to prevent empty fields in my search form

Tags: javascript, forms

I am absolutely beginner in javascript and i try to make my (2 fields what and where) search form  not submited if the 2 or the 1 of the 2 fields are empty and appear a message for example " Empty fields not allowed ".

My 2 fields are:

```
<input id="cf28" class="fxsearch_a1" type="text" size="30" name="cf28" />
<input id="city3" class="fxsearch_b1" type="text" size="30" name="city" />
```

Thanx & Waiting for your help...

Here is all my code..

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function showlayer(layer) {
var mymenu = document.getElementById(layer).style.display;
if (mymenu == "block") {
document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "none";
} else {
document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "block";
}
}
// ]]>

</script>
</p>
<p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function initialize() {
var input = document.getElementById('city3');
var options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
componentRestrictions: {
country: "gr"
}
};
// var options = {
//  types: ['(regions)']
// };
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
// ]]>

</script>
</p>
<div class="fixedsearch">
<form id="Simplesearchform" action="index.php" method="post" name="Simplesearchform">  <select id="searchcondition" class="inputbox" style="display: none;" name="searchcondition" size="1"><option value="1">option 1</option><option selected="selected" value="2">option 2</option></select>
<div class="fxbrowse">
<p id="showorHide" class="browsing"><a onclick="javascript:showlayer('mymenu')">My Menu</a>
</p>
</div>
<div class="fxgroupfields">
<div class="what">What?</div><input id="cf28" class="fxsearch_a1" type="text" size="30" name="cf28" />
<div class="where">Where?</div><input id="city3" class="fxsearch_b1" type="text" size="30" name="city" /><input id="submit" class="fxbutton" type="submit" value="GO" />
</div><input type="hidden" value="103" name="Itemid" /><input type="hidden" value="com_mtree" name="option" /><input type="hidden" value="advsearch2" name="task" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="mymenu" class="menubrowse">
<div class="menulinks"><a href="catalog" target="_self">My Catalog</a>
</div>
<div class="menulinks"><a href="catalog/add" target="_self">Add New</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake i edited the tag. You are right its JavaScript

Comment: No problem, just so long as you understand the distinction going forward. The tags are your best friends for attracting experts for your problem, so it is extremely important to get them right. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Takis, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is tagged Java, I think you mean Javascript.

For vanilla Javascript, you could do something like this:

```
// Generic validation function to ensure you Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)
function validate(obj) {
    if (!obj.value) {
        document.getElementById('yourmessageelement').innerHTML =
            "Empty fields not allowed!";
    }
}

// Event handlers for blur (when an element loses focus)
document.getElementById('cf28').onblur = function() {
    validate(this);
}

document.getElementById('city3').onblur = function() {
    validate(this);
}
```

If you don't want the user submitting the form with empty fields, you'll need to `disabled` the submit button somewhere too, with this line of code:

```
document.getElementById('yoursubmitbutton').disabled = 'disabled';
```

Libraries like JQuery will help with this but they have a learning curve, and also it's good to know how to do stuff yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your time i just copied & pasted your code but doesnt work. When i click on submit button it searches with empty fields and returning all the results from the database !!!

Comment: Currently you don't have id's in your html. And @Steve was using getElementById. So just in your html input tags add id='cf28' and id='city'

Comment: @Pompey - actually he did have IDs, I was using his.  What won't work is the IDs I made up: `yourmessageelement` and `yoursubmitbutton`.  You need to add IDs to your message element and your submit button.  Also, put `disabled='disabled'` in your submit button HTML so it's disabled to start with :) That will fix your submit problem.

Comment: @Steve i made the changes you mentioned but i dont know what is the message element id or how to create one.

Comment: Well, you have to show your users the message somehow, right? So you'll have an element like a `<div>` or `<p>` or `<span>` that will hold the message text. Give it an ID and you can use `.innerHTML` to show messages in it.

Comment: @Steve Oh i see :) i ll give it a try. I guess that i have to read dozens of javascript books to learn programming but i will not give up. PS i aprecciate your help fellows

Comment: No worries.  If an answer solves your question here on SO the community appreciates if you mark it "accepted".  And no, not dozens of books - just do what you're doing right now, try stuff, play around.  It's frustrating for a week or two then it gels and you'll be able to do a lot of stuff.  A little bit at a time - you can do it!

Comment: Oh also BTW try to avoid having the `name` and `id` attribute the same.  In old browsers that will cause massive headaches so get out of the habit now.  Save you hours down the line.

Comment: @Steve Well...unfortunately after many hours of trying names and ids i can't make it work ! I tried everything and really i cant understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @Steve As you can see i added all the code i wrote so you can see where are the bugs. I am using google places autocomplete for the field "where".

Comment: @Takis you've got a whole bunch of other stuff in there, no wonder you're confused!  Boil it down to just what you need - take out the maps API stuff, all the extra html elements, and get your original question working without any bells and whistles.  If you have all of this extra crap you'll wind up gobsmacked by the complexity - not to mention, there may be an error coming from somewhere you don't expect!  Simplify  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).